Next.js intercepting routes feature doesn't work in production mode
I am trying to use Next.js intercepting routes feature. It works well locally in dev mode. Routes are not intercepting in production mode. The app is deployed on Vercel and there are some server errors.
package.json
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "ANALYZE=true next build",
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev -p 3004",
    "env:pull": "npx vercel@31 env pull .env --yes --environment=preview",
    "lint": "eslint-configs-lint",
    "start": "next start -p 3004",
    "typecheck": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "algoliasearch": "^4.22.1",
    "framer-motion": "^11.0.5",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.mergewith": "^4.6.2",
    "next": "14.2.0-canary.60",
    "next-intl": "^3.7.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^7.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "2.4.1",
    "react-instantsearch": "^7.5.4",
    "react-photo-album": "^2.3.0",
    "react-popper": "^2.3.0",
    "search-insights": "^2.13.0",
    "tailwind-config": "*",
    "ts-deepmerge": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^14.0.4",
    "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.9",
    "@types/lodash.mergewith": "^4.6.9",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint-configs": "*",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

The app directory content:
├── [locale]
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   ├── page.tsx
│   ├── studio
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   ├── page.tsx
│   │   └── templatesnew
│   │       ├── @modal
│   │       │   ├── (.)[id]
│   │       │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │       │   └── default.tsx
│   │       ├── [id]
│   │       │   └── page.tsx
│   │       ├── _components
│   │       │   ├── navigation-sidebar
│   │       │   │   ├── all-templates-button.tsx
│   │       │   │   └── index.tsx
│   │       │   ├── page-content.tsx
│   │       │   ├── search-results
│   │       │   │   ├── index.tsx
│   │       │   │   └── search-results.tsx
│   │       │   └── templates-detail-modal
│   │       │       ├── index.tsx
│   │       │       └── templates-details-content.tsx
│   │       ├── context
│   │       │   └── templates-page.tsx
│   │       ├── default.tsx
│   │       ├── layout.tsx
│   │       └── page.tsx

templatesnew/layout.tsx
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'

import { locales } from '../../../../utils/locales'

//Needed for static rendering
//Docs on https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router#static-rendering

export default async function LocaleLayout({
  children,
  params: { locale },
  modal,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  params: { locale: string }
  modal: React.ReactNode
}) {
  // Validate that the incoming `locale` parameter is valid
  if (!locales.includes(locale)) {
    notFound()
  }
  //Needed for static rendering
  //Docs on https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router#static-rendering
  // unstable_setRequestLocale(locale)

  return (
    <>
      {children}
      {modal}
    </>
  )
}

templatesnew/page.tsx
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { getTranslations } from 'next-intl/server'
import * as React from 'react'
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl'

import { StudioHeader, Theme } from '@web/components/studio-header/'
import OGImage from '@web/assets/pages/studio/og-image.png'
import { PageContent } from './_components/page-content'

type StudioPageProps = {
  locale: string
}

export async function generateMetadata({
  params: { locale },
}: {
  params: StudioPageProps
}): Promise<Metadata> {
  const t = await getTranslations({ locale, namespace: 'pages.studio_templates.metadata' })

  return {
    metadataBase: new URL('https://www.creativefabrica.com/'),
    title: t('title'),
    description: t('description'),
    openGraph: {
      images: [OGImage.src],
    },
  }
}

export default function Templates() {
  //Needed for static rendering
  //Docs on https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router#static-rendering
  // unstable_setRequestLocale(locale)

  const t = useTranslations('pages.studio_templates')

  const pageContentProps = {
    searchPlaceholder: t('sidebar.search_placeholder'),
    categoriesTitle: t('sidebar.categories'),
    filtersTitle: t('sidebar.filters'),
    allCategoriesTitle: t('sidebar.all_categories'),
    allSubCategoriesTitle: t('sidebar.all_subcategories'),
    heroHeader: t('new_hero.h1'),
    resultsPreviousLabel: t('results.previous'),
    resultsNextLabel: t('results.next'),
    noResultsLabel: t('hero.no_results'),
    fstBreadCrumbLabel: t('new_hero.fst_breadcrumb'),
    sortViaLabel: t('filters.sort_via'),
    heroDescriptionFirst: t('new_hero.desc_fst'),
    heroDescriptionSecond: t('new_hero.desc_snd'),
  }

  return (
    <>
      <StudioHeader theme={Theme.LIGHT} />
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div />}>
        <PageContent {...pageContentProps} />
      </React.Suspense>
    </>
  )
}

templatesnew/[id]/page.tsx

import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { getTranslations } from 'next-intl/server'
import * as React from 'react'

import { StudioHeader, Theme } from '@web/components/studio-header/'
import OGImage from '@web/assets/pages/studio/og-image.png'
import { TemplateDetailsContent } from '../_components/templates-detail-modal/templates-details-content'

type StudioPageProps = {
  locale: string
}

export async function generateMetadata({
  params: { locale },
}: {
  params: StudioPageProps
}): Promise<Metadata> {
  const t = await getTranslations({ locale, namespace: 'pages.studio_templates.metadata' })

  return {
    metadataBase: new URL('https://www.creativefabrica.com/'),
    title: t('title'),
    description: t('description'),
    openGraph: {
      images: [OGImage.src],
    },
  }
}

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export default function Templates() {
  //Needed for static rendering
  //Docs on https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router#static-rendering
  // unstable_setRequestLocale(locale)

  return (
    <>
      <StudioHeader theme={Theme.LIGHT} />
      <div className="flex w-full items-start justify-center pb-6 pt-9">
        <div className="flex w-[calc(100vw-124px)] max-w-[1276px] flex-col">
          <TemplateDetailsContent />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

templatesnew/@modal/(.)[id]/page.tsx
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { getTranslations } from 'next-intl/server'
import * as React from 'react'

import OGImage from '@web/assets/pages/studio/og-image.png'
import { TemplatesDetailModal } from '../../_components/templates-detail-modal'

type StudioPageProps = {
  locale: string
}

export async function generateMetadata({
  params: { locale },
}: {
  params: StudioPageProps
}): Promise<Metadata> {
  const t = await getTranslations({ locale, namespace: 'pages.studio_templates.metadata' })

  return {
    metadataBase: new URL('https://www.creativefabrica.com/'),
    title: t('title'),
    description: t('description'),
    openGraph: {
      images: [OGImage.src],
    },
  }
}

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export default function Templates() {
  //Needed for static rendering
  //Docs on https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router#static-rendering
  // unstable_setRequestLocale(locale)

  return <TemplatesDetailModal />
}


The errors from Vercel's server log:



I tried to use on of the latest next.js canary versions. I tried to remove unstable_setRequestLocale and I tried to use export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic', but no difference.

Have you found any solution to that? I'm facing a similar issue.
